# Intersect lists in racket

Tags: racket

I want to create function that takes as parameters two lists and returns `#t` if they intersect (have any elements in common).

```
 (define member?
  (lambda (a lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) #f)
      (else (or (equal? (car lat) a) 
                (member? a (cdr lat)))))))
(define intersect
  (lambda (set1 set2)
    (cond
      ((null? set1)(quote ()))
      ((member? (car set1) set2)
       (cons (car set1)
             (intersect (cdr set1) set2)))


      (else (intersect (cdr set1) set2)))))

(intersect '(1 2) '(2 4)) ;
```

Comment: Your question asks about two lines, but the answer you accepted seems to be about the intersection of two lists — and, at least in the world outside Racket, lines and lists are quite different types.  Are you sure your question as originally written was correct referring to lines?  I made the title more meaningful; please fix it too if 'lines' should be 'lists'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Since you have edited I guess you did look at previous versions that had actual code in it? I'd say that was more set theory than geometry.

Comment: @Sylwester: no, I didn't previously look at the edit history.  I wonder why the code was removed.  It reduces the quality of the question enormously.  I agree that is lists rather than lines.  I did wonder how the answers deduced what was required; now I see.  I will re-edit, reinstating the code and changing line to list.

Comment: Please do not destroy a question after you've received an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at [sets in the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html). With them intersect can be written:

```scm
(define (intersect? lst1 lst2)
  (let ((set1 (list->set lst1))
        (set2 (list->set lst2)))
    (set=? set1
           (set-intersect set1
                          set2))))

(intersect? '(a b) '(b a d)) ; ==> #t
(intersect? '(b a d) '(a b)) ; ==> #f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the intersection of *geometric* lines, you should take a look at [this file](https://github.com/VincentToups/racket-lib/blob/master/utilities/planar-geometry.rkt). It has lots of geometric structures and functions, and you can see the intersection code [here](https://github.com/VincentToups/racket-lib/blob/master/utilities/planar-geometry.rkt#L386). Even if your lines use a different structure, the algorithm here should work with some tweaking.